# Parsing String data to int (Failed assertion: line 32 pos 14: 'prevReading is int': is not true.)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

im getting this error while parsing my String data from foreach to integer. Any ways to solve this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that myElement is a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` statements in dart are used to validate a certain condition that you provide it and then throw an error if that condition has not been satisfied.

In your case,

```
asert(prevReading is int)
```

is there to check whether the `prevReading` is actually an `int` or not and it is doing it's job perfectly and thus the error is coming.

You, `int.tryParse` is a function that takes a `String` and returns an `int` if the parsing succeeds. But it will return a `null` if the parsing fails.

So, in your case it is safe to say that the parsing has failed since your `myElement` is not a `String` representation of an `int`.

Depending on your goal, one way to avoid this is to remove the `assert` statement.

Comment: Figured it out!! the error was the first row of the data im trying to parse which is a header and eventualy will result to null.   appreciate your reply dude! Thanks!